# How to code a pixel-based GUI drawing system + scaling the size in Roblox Luau

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, roblox, luau

I wish to create a drawing system that turns whatever shape you draw into an array looking like

```
local Drawing = { -- Simple box drawing
   "11111",
   "10001",
   "10001",
   "10001",
   "11111",
}
```

If you are interested in full use case:
I am trying to make a symbol-recognizing system (not neural networking, isn't fast enough for me needs) with template-matching algorithms like sum of absolute differences or normalized cross correlation. I make a answer symbol with the 0s and 1s like the drawing above, then compare them to each to see whichever is closest. (Sorry if this should be another topic, but if you know a more performant/efficient way of comparing them I am all ears!)

However the problem I currently having is making a **grid-based drawing system** and **scaling the drawing**.

1. I thought of having a bunch of frame in a grid, then detect when the mouse hovers over each (with the mouseHover event). I also thought of just rounding the mouse position. This is mostly sorted out for me, however I was wondering how others would implement this kind of system.
2. I want the drawing to be converted no matter its size, into a designated size, like 5x5 or 10x10 to fit the original drawing template. I thought of finding the boundary box of the drawing, then trying to "compress" (divide) each individual mouse position I would cache while moving the mouse. However this would need me to use a ton of memory and I doubt it is extremely optimal, especially if you just keep the mouse down to play the event for a very long time. Also, would there be a way to possibly stop "outliers" from occurring? A small line outside the draw-line could potentially break it. Is there an alternative algorithm I can use?

Thank you for reading, also let me know if any formatting here is incorrect I am new to stack-overflow.

Comment: Was the answer on your previous question unhelpful?

Comment: No, it was very helpful. I just underestimated how I would convert the drawing into 0s and 1s, which is my bad.